# Способ изложения текста (индуктивный, дедуктивный) – 2

Tags: риторика

Существенные сдвиги в общественной жизни, происшедшие на рубеже средневековья и нового времени, вызвали серьёзные изменения и в языке. Развитие экономических и политических связей Московской Руси, рост авторитета Москвы, распространение документов московских приказов способствовали росту влияния устной речи Москвы на территории Московской Руси. Это явилось причиной того, что говор Москвы лёг в основу начавшего формироваться в 17 в. русского национального языка. Формированию национального литературного языка способствовало всё более широкое распространение в демократических слоях общества литературы, язык которой сложился на основе устной и деловой речи. Образование и наука становятся более светскими.

Я так понимаю, это тоже индуктивный. Сперва указываются факты, а потом тезис: Образование и наука становятся более светскими.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могу найти связи между всем текстом и последней фразой. Все время говорится об изменении, формировании языка и вдруг – "образование и наука становятся более светскими" – фраза, логически не связанная с предыдущим текстом. Не нахожу ничего лучшего, чем проигнорировать ее. Далее все просто: тезис содержится в первой фразе (в языке произошли изменения), а остальной текст раскрывает, конкретизирует этот тезис. Использован **дедуктивный** способ.